# ¿Cómo eliminar una fila de un dataframe en función al contenido de una columna?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo el siguiente `dataframe`.

```
0                                               Línea   Descripción
Product Line:      (RC)                             0             0
000400159559,"DAN HAMBURGUESA 500GR          "    162          (RC)
000400837825,"DAN HAMBURGUESA PRECOCIDA 480G "    162          (RC) 
Product Line:      (RS)                             0             0
```

Necesito eliminar las filas que comienzen con `Product Line`, entiendo que tengo que utilizar el código `startswith` pero no se como enlazarlo para eliminar la respectiva fila.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como se menciona en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35186529/6836377), la forma más segura de eliminar las filas en función a que una columna no comience con un determinado texto sería:

```
df[~df['linea'].astype(str).str.startswith('Product Line:')]
```

- El `astype(str)` se puede obviar si tenemos seguridad que la columna es una cadena
- Con `~` negamos la condición

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = [
          ['Product Line:      (RC)', 1],
          ['000400159559,"DAN HAMBURGUESA 500GR          ', 2],
          ['000400837825,"DAN HAMBURGUESA PRECOCIDA 480G "', 3],
          ['Product Line:      (RS)"', 4]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=['linea', 'valor'])
print(df)
print(df[~df['linea'].astype(str).str.startswith('Product Line:')])

                                            linea  valor    
0                         Product Line:      (RC)      1
1   000400159559,"DAN HAMBURGUESA 500GR                2
2  000400837825,"DAN HAMBURGUESA PRECOCIDA 480G "      3
3                        Product Line:      (RS)"      4

                                            linea  valor
1   000400159559,"DAN HAMBURGUESA 500GR                2
2  000400837825,"DAN HAMBURGUESA PRECOCIDA 480G "      3
```